# Interface builder won't change focus when selecting a warning

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5, warnings

I have several warnings in IB after upgrading to Xcode 5.1. When I select one of them, it seems like IB is trying to select the object generating the warning, but fails. My project is huge, and to look through all objects would take quite some time. Is there any other way to find the objects IB is complaining about?

Comment: I don't think so. IB will always complain about ViewControllers without segues or storyboard identifiers, viewcontroller's segues without identifiers and cell's without identifiers. So these are the things to look for, but I agree IB should highlight the issue for you.